# Sending email using sidekiq, redis

Tags: ruby, email, redis, sidekiq

I have a question about sidekiq in ruby.
I'm building a system to send campaign email, 10k - 50k emails/campaign.
For now i'm using Redis and Sidekiq, for every email I create a worker, like this:

```
receivers.each do |receiver|
    begin
      email_sending_log = EmailSendingLog.create(email: 
        receiver["email"], sender: sender["email"], content: 
        content["value"], status: "REQUESTED")
        EmailWorker.perform_async(adapter, receiver, sender, content, subject, email_sending_log.id.to_s)
    rescue Exception => e
    end
end
```

But it's so slow, 
Do you guys have any idea to speed up my system?
Or some example to speed up sidekiq, redis ?

Comment: "any idea to speed up my system" - yes. First step is to find what __exactly__ is slow. Only then you can start thinking about improving it.

Comment: yah, but actually I dont really understand why it's so slow.
Did i use sidekiq the right way?

Comment: Guess what, neither do we [understand why _your_ app is so slow].

Comment: "Did i use sidekiq the right way?" - yep, sidekiq api usage here seems fine.

Comment: @TungLe : circle out what the problem is - is your producer slow, i.e, is ur above code to generate EmailWorker is slow? Is your consumer slow?, ie., are consumers clients running enough to handle the load? does each worker process take too much time to be completed? Monitor in web ui for instance. Also, read about sidekiq concurrency (tradeoff). Is it 3rd party call (say SES) which is slowing you down? Just few things i could thing from top of my head.

Comment: I just find out put the loop in to the Worker is really faster than create a Worker thounsands time.  I think that's problem

Comment: @Kyle long loop in the Worker isn't good. I've added an answer why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending campaign emails is pretty standard task - one has to send N email(your N=10k..50k).
Beginners choose two opposite ways: one background job with N-loop OR N background jobs with one sending.

Both are bad:

- Long N-loop is vulnerable to errors and force shutdowns(app deploy
  etc) - a lot of messages might be send twice and a lot of ones might be lost.
- N-jobs takes a lot of time due to job processing overhead(your case).

What to do?

**Batches.** Use M jobs with K-loop each where M*K=N. Example: 100+ jobs with 100-loop each for your case. Try different M, K and choose best one for you. It's not a silver bullet but a golden mean of the bad opposite ways.

**Email sending services.** If your campaign is [marketing emails](https://sendgrid.com/blog/marketing-email-vs-transactional-email-whats-difference/)(I think it is), the best way is to use email sending services like Sendgrid, SES, Mailchimp, Mailgun, Elasticemail and so on.
They allow you to create email template(with substitutions) per campaign and then do whole campaign sending with just one API call(with addresses and substitutions as parameters of the call). It's fastest and the most reliable way, moreover email sending services provide additional benefits. The only drawback is it is paid.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer Pavel, u have a lot of experience about this

Comment: Yes I have: It's very common to send same ad. email to all registered users.